# How do I tell when Direct2D work has finished on the gpu

Tags: direct2d, direct3d11

The Direct2D API (i.e. `EndDraw`) executes asynchronously on the gpu. So how do I tell (on the cpu) that the work (on the gpu) is finished?

<strike>I'm hanging the device by calling `IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample` straight after  I finish rendering `ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw`.</strike>

P.S. I'm going to try the `ID3D11Fence` api

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_3/nn-d3d11_3-id3d11fence
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_4/nf-d3d11_4-id3d11device5-createfence

Comment: D2D is completely built over D3D11 and does not expose the underlying D3D11 objects and shaders it uses internally. Fencing is more for D3D12 and interop with it (since D3D12 leaves more work to developer). Sounds like a XY problem. Why do you need that? Do you have a reproducing sample code?

Comment: @SimonMourier I obtained a `IDXGIDevice` from a `ID3D11Device` and passed that to [D2D1CreateDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-d2d1createdevice). Seems like that exposes the underlying D3D11 device, and my code is producing the correct result. (P.S. the hang was caused by something else, so I'm not really sure that the fences are actually needed after all, and that what I've done is correct)

Comment: @SimonMourier actually I was using [`CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/id2d1devicecontext-createbitmapfromdxgisurface-overload) which requires `The DXGI surface must have been created from the same Direct3D device that the Direct2D device context is associated with.` so I was obtaining the underlying D3D11 object correctly

Comment: Underlying DXGI/D3D11 devices are not really "exposed", you just need one to use D2D. But for doing its work, D2D uses lots of other underlying objects (D3D1 render target, D3D11 command list, shaders, etc.). These you don't have access so you can't wait on anything. It's not clear what problem you have. You may want to enable debug layer too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/ for extra diags

Comment: I figured out what to do and don't have any problem. Calling [`ID3D11DeviceContext4::Signal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_3/nf-d3d11_3-id3d11devicecontext4-signal) after `EndDraw` does the trick it seems.